# How does one read a string which is the parameter of function in C?

Tags: c, string, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to create a hash key function which will operate on a given string. However, since in C a string is an array of type char where the length of the array will not match the length of a user input string, I am having trouble figuring out how I can read the given string without reading past that which the user has entered.

I tried using calloc but it doesn't seem possible to initialize within the parameter of a function

```
    int hashKey(char *c = calloc(100, sizeof(char)){
    int i = 0;
    int k;
    int h = 0;
    while (*(c+i) != 0){
         i++;
    }

    for(k = 0; k<i; k++){
         h += *(c+k);
    }
    h = h%10;
    return h;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in C are nul terminated char arrays so you can simply continue until you meet the string termination (nul).

For instance:

```
int hashKey(char *c){
    int k;
    int h = 0;

    for(k = 0; c[k]; k++){
           //  ^^^ stop when the termination is reached
         h += *(c+k);  // or: h += c[k];
    }

    h = h%10;
    return h;
}
```

An alternative implementation could be:

```
int hashKey(char *c){
    int h = 0;

    while(*c){
         h += *c;
         ++c;   // Move to next char
    }

    h = h%10;
    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the length of the string beforhand in your case.

Just do your hash calculations in the `while` loop, i.e.

```
while (c[i] != 0)
{
    // calc. hash
}
```

If you do need the string length, you can either have the caller provide it or use the `strlen()` function. The first option should be preferred, if performance is an issue.